# Reverse debugging for languages other than C/C++

Tags: java, ruby, debugging

Recently, I started to use [reverse debugging with gdb](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ReverseDebug) in C++ and it works pretty well for certain types of problems (e.g., loops and recursive algorithms). Besides gdb, there are other commercial debuggers for C/C++ (e.g., [UndoDB](http://undo-software.com/product/undodb-overview)).

I wonder if there are good reversible debuggers for other languages?
I'm especially interested in Java and Ruby but the question is open to any language.

An alternative that I found is to run your application on a virtual machine and connect to it. The only implementation that I know of (but never tested) is [VMware's Replay Debugging](http://www.replaydebugging.com/2008/08/vmware-workstation-65-reverse-and.). I wonder for which types of debugging tasks it is suitable. Seems to be overkill for most common problems but it may be useful to debug communication or synchronization issues, which are generally hard to reproduce.

Background information:

- The term "Reverse Debugging" is used by gdb. However, there are many synonyms:

  - "Reversible Debugging"
  - Microsoft calls it IntelliTrace or "Historical Debugging"
  - In Java, such debuggers are sometimes known as an "Ominiscient Debugger"
- (on programmers.stackexchange) [Why is reverse debugging rarely used?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/181527/why-is-reverse-debugging-rarely-used)

Comment: Your could checkout [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jakob_Engblom/publication/261039109_A_review_of_reverse_debugging/links/54f70fed0cf2ccffe9d9a19b.pdf) review paper on reverse debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Why is reverse debugging rarely used?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/181527/why-is-reverse-debugging-rarely-used) (on programmers.stackexchange), Jakob Engblom posted a great summary on the current state of reverse debugging:

- http://jakob.engbloms.se/archives/1547 - the tech
- http://jakob.engbloms.se/archives/1554 - research
- http://jakob.engbloms.se/archives/1564 - products
- http://jakob.engbloms.se/archives/1768 - updates to the previous post

Answer (score 2):

[Jiva](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/jive/) claims that it can:

> JIVE supports both forward and reverse stepping of Java programs. ... Providing the ability to step backwards saves a programmer the time and effort of re-executing the program until the point of error. JIVE also provides the ability to jump directly back to any previous point in the execution history in order to observe the object diagram at that point.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen I had a look on the tutorials on this project, however, it doesn't give enough information on the reverse debugging feature. Actually the tool is jumping among the history of the objects or thread, which is showing the metadata of the program state you want to see but not "run back" the program. It's more like a program state monitor but not a good tool for reverse debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for this rather belated reply.  Yes, JIVE's reverse stepping is very effective for debugging.  You can step or jump back to any point in the execution history.

You can also pose queries over the execution history, e.g., "Show all changes to x",  "When did x first become negative",  "Was this line of code ever executed; if so where?", etc.  All this can be done through a simple form-based query.

http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/jive

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look on the `Omniscient Debugging` which is refereed as the ODB by the author Bil Lewis [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0310016). ODB is an implementation of the **offline log** and **replay** way to make reverse debugging in **Java** come true.